# How to wrap text in list picker silverlight toolkit?

Tags: windows-phone-7, silverlight-toolkit

Here is my XAML

```
 <toolkit:ListPicker.FullModeItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="16 21 0 20">
                            <Rectangle Width="43" Height="43"/>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding AccountDescription}" Margin="16 0 0 0" FontSize="43" FontFamily="{StaticResource PhoneFontFamilyLight}" TextWrapping="Wrap"/>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </toolkit:ListPicker.FullModeItemTemplate>
```

Even though I added TextWrapping = "Wrap"
My TextBlock doesn't wrap
Am I missing something?

Comment: Setting Width on your TextBox does not help? try to set width to 300

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try replacing the `StackPanel` with a `Grid` (I don't have a compiler handy, typing from memory, so there may be some typos):

```
<toolkit:ListPicker.FullModeItemTemplate>
  <DataTemplate>
    <Grid Margin="16 21 0 20">
      <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
      </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

      <Rectangle Width="43" Height="43" Grid.Column="0" />
      <TextBlock Text="{Binding AccountDescription}" Margin="16 0 0 0" 
                 FontSize="43" FontFamily="{StaticResource PhoneFontFamilyLight}" 
                 TextWrapping="Wrap" Grid.Column="1" />
    </Grid>
  </DataTemplate>
</toolkit:ListPicker.FullModeItemTemplate>
```

Also, instead of hard coding things like `FontSize` and `Margin`, you may want to use predefined [theme resources](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff769552%28VS.92%29.aspx) instead. Jeff Wilcox has a [blog post](http://www.jeff.wilcox.name/2011/03/metro-design-guide-v1/) with numerous such best practices for UI design.

Comment: Yes, I read that blog post few days ago. I'll try this and will see the results

Answer (score 1):

Just remove `Orientation="Horizontal"` from stackpanel.